# Using a zipped file as a shell stdin

Tags: python, shell, gzip

I'm trying to write a short script that will recover a repository.
The backup script generates dump files that are gzipped.

To apply a dump I need to call this command:

```
svnadmin load < myfile
```

but since myfile is a gzipped one, I need to unzip it for the command to work.

Now here comes my question, is the command on top same as

```
subprocess.call(['svnadmin','load', myfilecontents])
```

This way I will avoid the need to unzip the file, to a temporary location.
or should I be using

```
subprocess.call(['svnadmin','load'],stdin=gzip.open(myfile))
```

Comment: `zcat myfile | svnadmin load` is more likely to be the command you want to model with `subprocess`... (or `gzip -dc`, if for some reason, your distro of choice doesn't provide `zcat`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't point `stdin` at a `GzipFile`, but you can copy the data yourself

```
In [5]: cmd=subprocess.Popen(["od", "-cx"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
In [6]: data=gzip.open("/tmp/hello.gz")
In [8]: cmd.stdin.write(data.read())
In [9]: cmd.stdin.close()
0000000   h   i  \n
           6968    000a
0000003
```

Alternatively, you could use `Popen.communicate()`:

```
In [11]: cmd=subprocess.Popen(["od", "-cx"], 
                               stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                               stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
In [12]: data=gzip.open("/tmp/hello.gz")
In [13]: cmd.communicate(data.read())
Out[13]: ('0000000   h   i  \\n\n           6968    000a\n0000003\n', '')
```

Comment: Agreed, and if twalberg creates an answer based on his comment, I'd probably upvote it.